# Why can't I play ISO's in MythTV 0.22?

Tags: mythtv, mythbuntu

When trying to play any video in MythVideo that is an ISO, it fails to play. Playing other types of videos is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage Groups are a streaming method of transmitting material to a frontend, meaning they don't provide block-level access to the file in question. An ISO is a disk image, and libdvdnav/libdvdcss, the libraries used to view DVDs/DVD images, requires block-level access. See [MythVideo - Disadvantages](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MythVideo#Disadvantages)

This is resolved in MythTV 0.24 and later